# Writing conditions on Where clause is better or ON clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Which query is standard and optimal?

This:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p
JOIN favorites f ON p.id = f.post_id
WHERE f.user_id = ?
```

Or this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p
JOIN favorites f ON p.id = f.post_id
 AND f.user_id = ?
```

Comment: If it was a *left* join then both queries may return different results, In case of *inner* join they will produce same results

Comment: Personally, I think a where clause makes it more obvious you are filtering for something specific. It also makes it less error prone if you need to turn the join into a left join. Other than that, it's just preference; hence voted to close for primarily opinion based.

Comment: They are equivalent.  I think the first is more common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both query have written in standard way, it will work in almost all *DBMS*. But, if you concerned about the performance then i would use `EXISTS` instead.

```
select p.*
from posts p
where exists (select 1 
              from favorites f 
              where p.id = f.post_id and f.user_id = ?
             );
```

For me doing filter in `ON` clause or in `WHERE` clause just the metter of style how it looks for `INNER JOIN`. So, i would go with `WHERE` clause :

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p INNER JOIN 
     favorites f 
     ON p.id = f.post_id
WHERE f.user_id = ? 
ORDER BY f.date_time DESC;
```

Comment: Well in reality there is also `ORDER BY f.date_time DESC` and your query cannot support it